# How to read multiple lines using FileReader only?

Tags: java, filereader

I have the following code:

```
public class Reader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (FileReader in = new FileReader("D:/test.txt")) {
            // BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
            int line = in .read();
            for (int i = 0; i < line; i++) {
                //System.out.println(line);

                System.out.println((char) line);
                line = in .read();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and a file `Test.txt` with the content:

> ```
> Hello
> Java
> ```

When I run above code it only reads `Hello`. I would like to read multiple lines using `FileReader` only. I don't want to use `BufferedReader` or `InputStreamReader` etc. Is that possible?

Comment: I'm assuming the real `test.txt` contains integers instead of Strings though. :-P

Comment: Any reasons why you want to use only FileReader ?

Comment: This code read all characters for me (including lines separators). Are you sure you are not oversimplifying your example?

Comment: @Ceiling Gecko test.txt contains Hello in the first line and Java in the second line.

Comment: @Jay because I want to know a way to read multiple lines using FileReader and increase my knowledge regarding FileReader.

Comment: @Pshemo plz copy this code and try it only prints Hello that is in the first line,it doesn't read Java because it is in the second line.

Comment: @TruePS I did. Lets try it different way. Test this code http://pastebin.com/hmWME7aF. It gives me this result http://pastebin.com/s8zpmxEn. It is vertical, but it prints all characters from file (even line separators).

Comment: @Pshemo This is my actual text file test.txt here it reads only "My name" when I use for loop I don't know why http://www.sendspace.com/file/u9jqc6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading file character by character without any buffering stream is extremely ineffective. I would probably wrap FileReader in some BufferedReader or simply used Scanner to read condent of file, but if you absolutely want/need/have to use only FileReader then you can try with

```
int line = in.read();
while (line != -1) {
    System.out.print((char) line);
    line = in.read();
}
```

instead of your `for (int i = 0; i < line; i++) {...}` loop.

Read carefully [slims answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22199770/1393766). In short: reading condition shouldn't care if number of characters you read is less then numeric representation of currently read character (`i < line`). Like in case of

```
My name

is

not important now
```

This file has few characters which you normally will not see like `\r` and `\n` and in reality it looks like

```
My name\r\n 
\r\n 
is\r\n 
\r\n 
not important now
```

where numeric representation of `\r` is `10`, so after you read `My name\r\n` (which is 9 characters because `\r` and `\n` are single character representing line separator) your `i` will become `10` and since next character you will try to read is `\r` which is also represented by `10` your condition `i<line` will fail (`10<10` is not true).

So instead of checking `i<line` you should check if read value is not EoF (End of File, or End of Stream in out case) which is represented by `-1` as specified in [`read` method documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#read%28%29) so your condition should look like `line != -1`. And because you don't need `i` just use `while` loop here.

> **Returns:**
>
> The character read, or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached

Comment: thank you man just need one more help read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216398/can-bufferedreader-read-bytes here read my 3rd comment on the accepted answer regarding working of BufferedReader,plz try to tell me working of bufferedreader if you know,May god bless you.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this version of the code prints "Hello".

You are calling:

```
int line = in.read();
```

What does this do? Look in the Javadocs for `Reader`:

> public int read()
>
> throws IOException
>
> Reads **a single character**. This method will block until a character is available, an I/O error occurs, or the end
>   of the stream is reached.

(emphasis mine)

Your code reads the 'H' from 'Hello', which is 72 in ASCII.

Then it goes into your loop, with line==72, so it goes into the loop:

```
  for(int i=0;i<line;i++)
```

... making the decision "is 0 less than 72? Yes, so I'll go into the loop block".

Then each time it reads a character the value of `line` changes to another integer, and each time loop goes around `i` increments. So the loop says "Keep going for as long as the ASCII value of the character is greater than the number of iterations I've counted".

... and each time it goes around, it prints that character on a line of its own.

As it happens, for your input, it reads end-of-file (-1), and as `-1 < i`, the loop continue condition is not met.

But for longer inputs it stop on the first 'a' after the 97th character, or the first 'b' after the 98th character, and so on (because ASCII 'a' is 97, etc.)

```
H
e
l
l
o


J
a
v
a
```

This isn't what you want:

- You don't want your loop to repeat until i >= "the character I just read". You want it to repeat until `in.read()` returns `-1`. You have probably been taught how to loop until a condition is met.
- You don't want to `println()` each character, since that adds newlines you don't want. Use `print()`.

You should also look at the `Reader.read(byte[] buffer)` method, and see if you can write the code to work in bigger chunks.

---

Two patterns you'll use over and over again in your programming career are:

```
  Type x = getSomehow();
  while(someCondition(x)) {
      doSomethingWith(x);
      x = getSomehow();
  }
```

... and ...

```
  Type x = value_of_x_which_meets_condition;
  while(someCondition(x)) {
      x = getSomehow();
      doSomethingWith(x);
  }
```

See if you can construct something with `FileReader` and the value you get from it, filling in the "somehows".

Comment: Thanks for the advice bro but plz copy and paste this code and try yourself,I am also confused why it is printing Hello in the first place,but it is.

Comment: I ran it and it prints "H
e
l
l
o


J
a
v
a
"
.. with a newline replacing each space.
Perhaps you're not running the version you think you are?

Comment: thank you man just need one more help read this stackoverflow.com/questions/22216398/… here read my 3rd comment on the accepted answer regarding working of BufferedReader,plz try to tell me working of bufferedreader if you know,plz plz

Answer (score 1):

You will have to read the content char by char and parse for a new line sequence.

A new line sequence can be any of the following:

1. a single cariage return `'\r'`
2. a single line feed `'\n'`
3. a carriage return followed by a line feed `"\r\n"`

**EDIT**

You could try the following:

```
public List<String> readLinesUsingFileReader(String filename) throws IOException {
    List<String> lines = null;
    try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filename)) {
        lines = readLines(fileReader);
    }
    return lines;
}

private List<String> readLines(FileReader fileReader) throws IOException {
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean newLine = false;
    int c, p = 0;
    StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
    while(-1 != (c = fileReader.read())) {
        if(c == '\n' && p != '\r') {
            newLine = true;
        } else if(c == '\r') {
            newLine = true;
        } else {
            if(c != '\n' && c != '\r') {
                line.append((char) c);  
            }
        }
        if(newLine) {
            lines.add(line.toString());
            line = new StringBuilder();
            newLine = false;
        }
        p = c;
    }
    if(line.length() > 0) {
        lines.add(line.toString());
    }
    return lines;
}
```

Note that the code above reads the whole file into a `List`, this might not be well suited for large files! You may want in such a case to implement an approach which uses streaming, i.e. read one line at a time, for example `String readNextLine(FileReader fileReader) { ... }`.

Some basic tests:

Create test files to read

```
private final static String txt0 = "testnl0.txt";
private final static String txt1 = "testnl1.txt";
private final static String txt2 = "testnl2.txt";

@BeforeClass
public static void genTestFile() throws IOException {
    try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(txt0)) {
        os0.write((
            "Hello\n" +
            ",\r\n" +
            "World!" +
            "").getBytes());
    }

    try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(txt1)) {
        os.write((
            "\n" +
            "\r\r" +
            "\r\n" +
            "").getBytes());
    }

    try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(txt2)) {
        os.write(( 
            "").getBytes());
    }
}
```

Test using the created files

```
@Test
public void readLinesUsingFileReader0() throws IOException {
    List<String> lines = readLinesUsingFileReader(txt0);
    Assert.assertEquals(3, lines.size());
    Assert.assertEquals("Hello", lines.get(0));
    Assert.assertEquals(",", lines.get(1));
    Assert.assertEquals("World!", lines.get(2));
}

@Test
public void readLinesUsingFileReader1() throws IOException {
    List<String> lines = readLinesUsingFileReader(txt1);
    Assert.assertEquals(4, lines.size());
    Assert.assertEquals("", lines.get(0));
    Assert.assertEquals("", lines.get(1));
    Assert.assertEquals("", lines.get(2));
    Assert.assertEquals("", lines.get(3));
}

@Test
public void readLinesUsingFileReader2() throws IOException {
    List<String> lines = readLinesUsingFileReader(txt2);
    Assert.assertTrue(lines.isEmpty());
}
```

Comment: can you plz tell me how can I parse this in the above code.

Comment: plz also check [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225529/how-can-we-enhance-performance-using-hooking) .Thanks for this edit I understood it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the new line character

```
    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{
        FileReader in = new FileReader("D:/test.txt");
        char [] a = new char[50];
        in.read(a); // reads the content to the array
        for(char c : a)
            System.out.print(c); //prints the characters one by one
        in.close();
    }
```

It will print

```
Hello 
Java
```

Comment: Here you only want to use FileReader, which becomes a big constrain.

Comment: @Zhenxiao yes I wanna read unlimited characters using FileReader,Is that possible.

Comment: @TruePS Sorry, I'm not quite sure here.

Comment: @Zhenxia I got the answer yes we can plz check my answer for that.

Comment: @Zhenxiao No,I just used while loop instead of for loop.Do you know what is the meaning of OP?

Answer (score 0):

Reader.read() returns int code of single char or -1 if end of the file is reached:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read()

So, read the file char by char and check  LF (Line feed, '\n', 0x0A, 10 in decimal), CR (Carriage return, '\r', 0x0D, 13 in decimal)and end-of-line codes.

Note: Windows OS uses 2 chars to encode the end of line: "\r\n". The most of others including Linux, MacOS, etc. use only "\n" to encode the end of line.

```
    final StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder(); // line buffer

    try (FileReader in = new FileReader("D:/test.txt")) {            
        int chAr, prevChar = 0x0A; // chAr - just read char, prevChar - previously read char
        while (prevChar != -1) { // until the last read char is EOF
            chAr = in.read(); // read int code of the next char
            switch (chAr) {
                case 0x0D: // CR - just
                    break; // skip
                case -1:   // EOF
                    if (prevChar == 0x0A) {
                        break; // no need a new line if EOF goes right after LF
                               // or no any chars were read before (prevChar isn't 
                               // changed from its initial 0x0A)
                    }
                case 0x0A: // or LF
                    System.out.println("line:" + line.toString()); // get string from the line buffer
                    line.setLength(0); // cleanup the line buffer
                    break;
                default: // if any other char code is read
                    line.append((char) chAr); // append to the line buffer
            }
            prevChar = chAr; // remember the current char as previous one for the next iteration
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works great but unable to understand your code,can you explain it line by line

Answer (score 0):

I solved the above problem by using this code

```
     public class Reader 
      {
    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{
         try (FileReader in = new FileReader("D:/test.txt")) {
         int line = in.read();

         while(line!=-1)
         {
           System.out.print((char)line);
              line = in.read();
          }   }
     }
    }
```

But there is one more question if I write for loop instead of while like this

```
for(int i=0;i<line;i++)
```

It prints only first line.Could anybody tell me why?

Comment: Because it doesn't make sense. Comparing `i` to `line` is completely meaningless. `i` is a loop variable; `line`, which is severely misnamed, is a *character* read from a file. Why would you want to loop until `i` is equal to a character read from a file?

Comment: @EJP I understood your point of view completely but I was doing  little experiment so I just wanna know when I use for loop why I am unable to read second line.I hv also seen corresponding ASCII characters values I think the loop should work if i write i less than 100 than the loop read both lines.

Comment: It's not a 'point of view', it's a fact. There is nothing to understand about why nonsensical code doesn't execute as expected. It can't, because there can't be rational expectations about nonsense.