# How can we enhance performance using hooking?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

the Java Docs says [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)

> public class BufferedReader
>   extends Reader
>
> Reads text from a character-input stream, buffering characters so as to provide for the >efficient reading of characters, arrays, and lines.
>
> The buffer size may be specified, or the default size may be used. The default is large >enough for most purposes.
>
> In general, each read request made of a Reader causes a corresponding read request to be >made of the underlying character or byte stream. It is therefore advisable to wrap a >BufferedReader around any Reader whose read() operations may be costly, such as >FileReaders and InputStreamReaders. For example,
>
> BufferedReader in
>   = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("foo.in"));
>
> will buffer the input from the specified file. Without buffering, each invocation of >read() or readLine() could cause bytes to be read from the file, converted into >characters, and then returned, which can be very inefficient.

But by hooking Filereader we are using FileReader's read method to read file which reads one character at a time,So if my file contains 2000 characters FileReader firstly will read 2000 characters one at a time and transfer it to buffer and we will read that from buffer using bufferedreader so How it enhances performance.We could do it using FileReader only?

Comment: You _have_ to "read" one character at a time. `FileReader` turns a sequence of one or more bytes into viable characters; depending on the encoding used, a character may be encoded as several bytes. In the case of UTF-8 in particular, this can be as little as 1 byte or as much as 3 bytes. `BufferedReader` simply reduces the number of reads needed from the original file by buffering the results of the decoding operation.

Comment: @fge So you are saying in this case Filereader will read all characters at one time.

Comment: No, only by chunks; imagine a file several GiB large...

Comment: @fge How can it read large chunks it doesn't have readline() method to go to next line

Comment: It is the `BufferedReader` which will control that; or, in fact, any `Reader`. Look at the javadoc of `Reader`: it has methods to fill a `char[]` with characters.

Comment: @fge can you explain me the whole process of hooking and how output is displayed using a sample program.

Answer (score 2):

You could imagin it like this:

You are in location `A` and your data is at location `B` where `A` and `B` are 5km away from each other.

By retieving the data one unit at a time you have to make the travel (read request to be made of the underlying character or byte stream) from `A` to `B` each time, thus if you have 100 data units you are going to do the travel 100 times, and this is waht costs time.

Wehen Buffering you are like having a truck and when you do a travel you load some amount of data units (the size of the buffer) onto your load floor (the buffer) so that you don't have to make the travel a lot of times and thus be efficient.

Usually where you open a file for reading you want to read more that one charachter, therefore a BufferedRead is to be prefered.

The same applies for writing too.

**EDIT**

First off, `FileReader` does not read itself, it's the underlying input stream which does. In this case `FileInputStream`.

The `BufferedReader` manages the `FileReasder` for you, and it uses in its `fill()` method the method

```
abstract public int read(char cbuf[], int off, int len) throws IOException;
```

of your `Reader` to fill the buffuer. **It does not use the method which reads only a single character!** In other word, when the fill method has to do the *travel*, it retrieves a range of charcters from the underlying input stream and keeps it in memory, so that when you need to read, it first looks in the buffer, consumes it and re-fills it if necessary.

You could achieve the same by calling `read(char cbuf[], int off, int len)` of `FileReader` yourself, but then all you will have is a range of charcters which having for example the following text

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore
magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
```

may for example look like this

```
"onsetetur sadipscing elitr,\r\nsed diam nonumy eirmod temp"
```

and you will have to deal with it to find a line of text if you need one.

But you dont have to because `BufferedReader` takes care of this for you, and this is one of the reasons why you better write

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("foo.in"));
```

Comment: So you are saying in this case Filereader will read all characters at one time

Comment: @TruePS, No, which part of my answer made you think this?

Comment: Actually you very well explained the concept of buffering to me but I wanna know why is hooking of Filereader's instance in Bufferedreader's constructor necessary so when we do hooking and calls readline() method of BufferedReader will it internally call the read method of Filereader,if this happens then why should we need buffered reader because filereader's read method will read 1 character at a time and it wastes our time,Forget buffering concept now just tell meWhy wewrite                                                >BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("foo.in"));

Comment: @A4LI think you are wrong I can manage lines read by Filereader using read(char cbuf[], int off, int len).See this            `public class Reader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (FileReader in = new FileReader("D:/test.txt")) {
            char[] cbuf = new char[1000];
           
            int line = in.read(cbuf, 1, 100);
           while(line!=-1) {
                System.out.print(cbuf);
                line = in.read();
            }
        }
    }
}`

Comment: @TruePS, I think not! What your code does is reading a `range of characters` not a `single line`. Take for example the text I have pasted in my edit and use as buffer size and max lenght to read `36` and see what happens. Btw your call to read does not seem to be correct, it should be `in.read(cbuf, 0, 100);` and the while loop is broken, you print the same buffer over and over again without reading into it be cause you use the read method which returs a single char, but you do nothing with it. Compare the content of your text file with the output of your program, im sure they are different.

Comment: output is same and even if I write 0 in place of 1 the code works great and the output of program is same as of file I have 4 lines in my lines and it reads 4 lines and show the 4 lines as they are written in file(in 4 lines)so this proves that it reads line seperators.Here the size of buffer must be greater than size of length passed.Copy and paste this code and see for youself.I read following file this is my txt. file http://www.sendspace.com/file/u9jqc6

Comment: @TruePS Your file is only **67 bytes** and you read up to **99**, so the first read gets all the content and it is printed in the first while iteration, the next read of a single char returns `-1` and the while loop stops. Starting from `1` is (unless you realy know what you are doing) not correct!!! What is the content of `cbuf[0]`?? And the fact that the cbuf nowhere updated inside the while loop should have made you suspicious. Try your code with the text I have pasted in my edit and see what happens using `36`.

Comment: @TruePS Please read the javadoc of the APIs you use to be sure you use then the way they should. Please debug your code to understand what it actually does. If you cant use a debugger then you should start with learning that, it's very important!!! Only after when you write code that you understand, then you can make thoughts about performace.

Comment: can you plz refer me any link to learn debugging,I am using Netbeans and I searched to learn debugging but I was unable to get worthy link.

Comment: @TruePS Here is [short tutorial for the netbeans debugger](http://cobweb.cs.uga.edu/~shoulami/sp2009/cs1301/tutorial/NetBeansDebuggerTutorial/NetBeansDebuggerTutorial.htm) which covers the basic steps.

Answer (score 2):

The BufferedReader is a common example of using a buffer.

Let's decompose the read() method of BufferedReader (J7u51):

```
ensureOpen();
for (;;) {
    if (nextChar >= nChars) {
        fill();
        if (nextChar >= nChars)
            return -1;
    }
```

The fill() method (which calls the underlying reader) is invoked if and only if we ask for more characters than we've got from some previous calls.

```
    if (skipLF) {
        skipLF = false;
        if (cb[nextChar] == '\n') {
            nextChar++;
            continue;
        }
    }
    return cb[nextChar++];
}
```

Here we just return the appropriate value.

So BufferedReader always "reads more in case you'd like more later" and then, if you really want more, can give you "the more" efficiently.

Take a look at this example :

```
YourApp                   BufferedReader (bufferSize=10)        FileReader
read(1 character)   ->
                          buffer empty, load 10 characters  ->  disk latency 10 ms
                                                            <-  return 10 characters
                          buffer filled with 10 characters
                    <-    return 1 character, 9 remaining 
                          in buffer
read(1 character)   ->    
                    <-    return 1 character, 8 remaining 
                          in buffer
.
.
.
read(1 character)   ->    
                    <-    return 1 character, 0 remaining 
                          in buffer
```

The total execution time of the loop is 10 milliseconds + insignificant Java overhead.

Now, compare it with the unbuffered version :

```
YourApp                   FileReader

read(1 character)   ->
                          disk latency 10 ms
                    <-    return 1 character
read(1 character)   ->    
                          disk latency 10 ms
                    <-    return 1 character
.
.
.
read(1 character)   ->    
                          disk latency 10 ms
                    <-    return 1 character
```

The overhead caused by the HDD calls is much bigger than in the previous case.

Comment: I think I got it,I just wanna ask a couple of things in the last image Filereader return 10 characters,So how come it is returning 1 charcter(According to me from char array) in next two calls  if 10 characters are stored in char array so how come everytime disk latency is 10ms.The second question is that if We are hooking Filereader in Bufferedreader's constructor then when we call readline() method is it internally calling read method of filereader right?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `BufferedReader` does not read the wrapped `Reader` completely at one time.  Instead it reads chunks of a specific size (per default 8192 characters) if required.

Secondly, the reason to use a `BufferedReader` instead of directly using a `FileReader` is that accessing a file is much more complex than accessing an object in the memory.  So if you read a file line by line, you'd access the file system once per line.  Using a `BufferedReader`, you can reduce the count of read operations and thereby improve the performance of your code.

Comment: I could not give better answer.

Comment: @Robin                                                                >Firstly, BufferedReader does not read the wrapped Reader completely >at one time. Instead it reads chunks of a specific size (per default >8192 characters) if required.                                                            I know that all I am asking is what about time wasted in shifting data into buffer using FileReader which reads one char at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Who says `FileReader` instance will be used to read one character at a time?

The best solution for your question is to go directly to the source code of `BufferedReader`. If you look into this, you will see that, internally, `BufferedReader` will call the `read(char[],int,int)` method of the wrapped `FileReader` (or whatever `Reader` it wraps).

[Here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/io/BufferedReader.java#BufferedReader.read%28%29) you have the code for the `read` method of `BufferedReader`. The actual call to the wrapped `Reader` is performed in the `fill` method. I think it's worth checking it a bit.

Comment: Let's avoid read() function just tell me the benefit of hooking I can read file using FileReader also.

Comment: `BufferedReader` uses a character buffer, attempting to optimize the input from the file system. So let's say you read now 10 chars, then 8000 chars and then another 182 chars (with 3 distinct calls to the `read` method). If you use a wrapper with a buffer size of 8192 characters, it will cause the file to be accessed only once, by grabbing all the 8192 characters from the very beginning. Definitely, you could write this by yourself using only a `FileReader`, but that's what Java APIs are for: to provide you highly optimized functionality that you would have to write, otherwise, by yourself.

Comment: just one last question regarding your comment If I read 8192 characters using FileReader only then How the performance is affected because by hooking you explained in your answer `BufferedReader will call the read(char[],int,int) method of the wrapped FileReader`.If I am reading a file using Filereader and calls `read(char[],int,int) method` of Filereader i will get the same output without the use of buffer and hence I will save overhead due to buffering.